# Silverlight 3 - Visual Studio Tools

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to get started doing some Silverlight development. I am interested in learning about the out-of-browser support. I can create and run Silverlight 3 applications just fine. I have confirmed that I have Silverlight 3 instead of Silverlight 3 Beta. I have been able to confirm this because my API list includes Application.InstallStateChanged instead of Application.ExecutionStateChanged.

However, I do not have the option to enable my application to run offline in Visual Studio. I can see this option in this blog post (http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/updated-silvertwit-code-for-msdn-magazine/). Unfortunately, I do not have the option shown or the Reduce XAP size option. I have downloaded the Visual Studio tools from here (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9442b0f2-7465-417a-88f3-5e7b5409e9dd&displaylang=en).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you have any previous version of the Silverlight tools or SDK installed before installing the V3 tools?

Comment: I uninstalled all previous versions via the Add/Remove programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like John Papa is using a new version of visual studio possibly the VS2010 beta.

Try this tutorial instead

http://wildermuth.com/2009/03/18/Enabling_Out-of-Browser_Support_in_Silverlight_3

or

http://blogs.msdn.com/katriend/archive/2009/07/10/silverlight-3-out-of-browser-applications.aspx

Comment: That post details the manual steps to enable OOB in Silverlight 3 *beta*.  The steps have changed in RTW :)

Comment: this link provides the differences between beta and RTW.

http://blogs.msdn.com/katriend/archive/2009/07/10/silverlight-3-out-of-browser-applications.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Corrupted Install**
It looks like a corrupted install.  Try uninstalling and then see Allen Chen's advice here:
http://silverlight.net/forums/t/83226.aspx  including:
Silverlight3_Tools.exe /x:c:\temp /u to manually extract the SL 3 files and c:\temp\SPInstaller.exe to verify the tools install.

**Use Blend**
Also, If you have Blend 3 installed (preview [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=A04AA0AE-87BE-4201-A65E-E792859122FC&displaylang=en)) you can enable Out of the Browser inside of Blend.  See Project->Silverlight Project Options.

Answer (score 0):

One thing might be that your Silverlight developer runtime got corrupted/overwritten. Try installing it once and see if it solves...
http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight3/default.aspx